# how to create an a new user or role in tedenigne?

Tags: tdengine

While I’m using tdengine,I want to create different users to access different tables.After I installed the tdengine I know there is a default user root. But if want to make access control to different tables. How can do this? Does tdengine support access control and allow customers to create different users and tables which will be very common in other databases.
If tdengine supports create users or roles,how can I do that?
Can someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create a user by executing following SQL in the taos shell:

```
    CREATE USER <user_name> PASS <'password'>;
```

modify user's capability by executing below SQL in the taos shell:

```
    ALTER USER <user_name> PRIVILEGE <write|read>;
```